# How to customized bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, customization

There is a page, http://www.getbootstrap.sk/customize/index.html, but after you finish and compile and download the completed zip file - NOWHERE is anything giving even a clue as what to do with the darn files. ( I just installed the standard package though bower ).

SO what am I supposed to do with the downloaded customize files?

ALl I'm really trying to do is to stop my navbar items from disappearing when the width falls below 768px - I don't want them ever to disappear.

Comment: You need to copy the css/js files into your project. As to where to copy them to, it depends on your project's file structure/tree

Comment: Can you add some snapshots of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to download the library. You can use online libraries.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html="en">
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Course</title>
    <!-- Normalize -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssnormalize/cssnormalize.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- YOUR OWN CSS LIBRARY -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- JQUERY If you need it -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- YOUR OWN JS LIBRARY -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      ....
  </body>

</html>
```

However, if you want to download the library, you just have to move the `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` to the folders where you keep your `CSS` and your `JS` files, and reference them in the header of your web page.

For example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

**UPDATE**:

Based on [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), I suggest that, in order to avoid collapsing of the navbar, delete the class `navbar-collapse` from any element of your navigation bar.

> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the `.navbar-collapse`. The responsive navbar requires the collapse plug-in to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

Additionally, you have to delete the button that is shown every time the navbar collapses.

Something like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teshima82/oohzzs19/3/)

---

I will need to see your source code to help you in a better way. Meanwhile, I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap. How to make the navbar never collapsed**

1. In the [Grid system](http://www.getbootstrap.sk/customize/#grid-system) set the field `@grid-float-breakpoint` value of `0`.
2. Click the `Compile and Download` button at the bottom of the page.
3. Extract the files `bootstrap.css` and  `bootstrap.min.css` from the resulting archive.
4. Use them instead of the standard files `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` on your site.